# How to pass ViewController Reference to Router in VIPER design pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

**P.S:**
This is not a opinionated question. Its a legitimate doubt on wiring various modules in VIPER. Its a theoretical question so no code attached. I just need to know how do we wire up View-Presenter-Router in this specific case without breaking ground rules of `VIPER`

I am trying my hands-on with VIPER for the first time. Here is my fundamental understanding of VIPER.

**View:** Supposed to show UI Controls and capture `IBActions` and call its presenter's delegate method to process events

**Presenter:** Will process all the UI related data and prepares data for rendering and hands over the data back to View. Whenever a screen transition is required it calls its router and asks the router to perform transition

**P.S:** Presenter will not have any UIComponents in it. So no `import UIKit` statement in presenter.

**Router:** is responsible for performing screen transitions usually does it with the help of wireframes (optional but good to have such class in app)

**Interactor:** Contains all business logic.Presenter will call Interactor whenever processing based on business logic is required.

**Entity:** POJO classes (Simple Swift Objects or Core data entities).

**Now comes the question:**

If my assumptions are right, Presenter is supposed to be a plain Swift class with no `UIKit` access.

If true, assume I press a button on my `ViewControllerA` and I need to push another `ViewControllerB` on top of it, obviously `ViewControllerA` will talk to `PresenterA` and tells it that button is tapped, now `PresenterA` should talk to `RouterA` and tell it to push `ViewControllerB`.

Because Router can have access to `UIKit` I can easily create a new instance of `ViewControllerB` using storyboard instance or from xib, but in order to push that instance I need the ViewControllerA's instance.

But `PresenterA` can not hold a reference to `ViewControllerA` or can be passed as argument to `PresenterA` in function because `UIViewController` belongs to `UIKit` and Presenters are not supposed to have UI statements.

**Probable Solutions I can think of:**

**Solution 1:**

While creating Router instance, pass corresponding `ViewController` instance as a part of its init (Dependency injection phase) that way Router will always have reference to ViewController it belongs to

**Solution 2:**

Have a Router declare its protocol and implement it in ViewController and whenever reference to ViewController needed use delegate of Router. But this contradicts the rules of VIPER that routers are not supposed to talk to View.

Am I thinking straight? Am I right with my assumptions? If yes what is the correct way to deal with this problem, Please suggest

Comment: Since `Router` is the object responsible for navigation, it's natural it would hold the reference to `ViewControllerA`, since it presented it in the first place. Similarly, `Router` would hold the reference to `UINagivationController` or `UITabBarController` if your application uses them

Comment: @mag-zbc : I am in complete agreement with your statement, but my confusion is when to/how to pass the viewController reference to router? At the time of init? As a part of dependency injection? Then it creates a loop because to create ViewController I need router and router takes a reference to ViewController :(

Comment: You don't pass it at all - `ViewControllerA` is supposed to be presented by `Router` in the first place, so it should be **created** in the `Router` and `Router` should retain reference to it.

Comment: @mag-zbc: Sorry I think I am confused here, lets say I have loginVC and I need to present HomeVC on login, in that case LoginVC -> LoginPresenter -> LoginRouter  and login router will create a instance of HomeVC from storyboard and pushes it. In that case, HomeVC needs to create its own HomePresenter now the question is how to break dead lock I talked above. Please read -> as talks to in statement above

Comment: There should only be a single `Router` in entire application, that's the whole point of VIPER - a single object responsible for navigation, not each `ViewController` having its own router. Also, you speak of `ViewControllers` having their own `Presenters` each, where I would argue that `ViewControllers` should **be** `Presenters`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any advice or opinion regarding VIPER for iOS applications is debatable, since VIPER does not fit strictly into iOS's UIKit design. But if I may put my two cents into discussion:

First off, I would argue that `UIViewController` fits perfectly into the role of `Presenter` in VIPER pattern, therefore `ViewControllerA` doesn't need to talk to any class in between itself and `Router` - just communicate with `Router` directly.

Secondly, there is supposed to be only one `Router` object - because application has only one view/navigation stack. For that reason it's ideal to implement a `Singleton` pattern for `Router`, so `ViewControllerA` (or `Presenter`, if you'd rather have your `ViewControllers` perform the role of `View` in that pattern) doesn't need to keep a reference to `Router`.

Thirdly, you shouldn't need to pass the reference to `ViewControllerA` to your `Router` - `Router` should already have the reference to it, because `Router` was supposed to present it in the first place. Something like that:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
{
    // ...

    window?.rootViewController = Router.shared.rootViewController

    // ...
}

class Router
{
    static let shared = Router()

    let rootViewController = ViewControllerA() // or UINavigationController, or UITabBarController etc.
}
```

`Router` should keep track of navigation stack and keep reference to currently presented `ViewController`

But that is, like, my opinion.

Comment: @mag-zbc : Thanks a lot for taking your time and explaining things :) Hence +1 Gimme a minute to verify the fact you mentioned :)

Comment: @mag-zbc : Having a singleton wireframe/router makes sense :) Thanks lemme explore more on that :) Though I dont agree with making ViewController the presenter (merging operation of View and Presenter in ViewController) because than we will have same module structure as one we had in MVVM :) The whole idea was to avoid fat module issue that we faced with MVVM and making concern separation and making unit test more deeper and cleaner :)

Comment: Like I said, it's debatable. `ViewController` as `Presenter` doesn't necessarily have to be fat, since business logic belongs to `Interactor`. Similarity in certain aspects to other design patterns is not a fault by itself.

Comment: agreed, just don't wanna mess up with the design pattern scared of loosing out on the benefit design pattern inherently provides